# Flex Moving Image

Tags: image, apache-flex, scroll, move, buttonclick

I am working on a project where I have a background image that is going to move depending on what button a user clicks. The idea is that every time the user clicks on a button, the "map"(of which I have oversized for this purpose) in the background will scroll to a location and show a different UI. An example of this would be that user in on the home page, and they click to visit tours. The homepage UI will fade out(depending on if we have time to get that working), and then the map will move, giving the impression that we are traveling across the map. Then the UI for tours will fade in.

I'm new to flex, so I don't really know the ins and outs. But does anyone have ideas/tips for what we want to accomplish?

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq For the types of questions that are appropriate.  Since you are new to Flex, I suggest you start by taking a look at this documentation http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html specifically the using Flex 4.6 section.  Read through, get your bearings, try to accomplish your task, and then come back to StackOverflow if you have a specific problem you need answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use     <mx:Fade id="fadeOut" duration="500" alphaFrom="1.0" alphaTo="0.0"/>
    <mx:Fade id="fadeIn" duration="500" alphaFrom="0.0" alphaTo="1.0"/>
<mx:Image id="staticPhoto" hide="{fadeOut}" show="{fadeIn}" maintainAspectRatio="true" source=""/>
and change the source of image whenever user click on button.
```